# Is there a way to change the color of certain logs in the webserver of Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I made a custom plugin which returns some custom messages if the process succed.
I would like to find some logs faster.
I wonder if there is a way to change the color of those messages because it is a bit time consuming to find for those logs.

Comment: what version are you using ? Check if this is what you are asking https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5681

Comment: colored_console_log try this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html

Comment: I will suggest check colored options which might be helpful

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon, my version is 1.10.10, thanks, I will have a look to the links , until know they seem very useful for what I want to do.